# A contradiction proof of "If $((n^q)-1)$ is divisible by $p,$ then show that $\,q \mid (p-1)"$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $\,p, q\,$ be prime numbers and $\,n\,\in \mathbb N$ such that $(n-1)$ is **not** divisible by $p$. If $\,(n^q-1)\,$ is divisible by p then show that  $q \mid (p-1)$.

How can I prove it by contradiction.  Let us take    $(p-1)$ is not divisible by $q$ then how can I achieve a contradiction to to show that  $(n^q-1)$ is not divisible by $p$.

Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can write $$n^q - 1 = (n-1)(n^{q-1} + n^{q-2} + n^{q - 3} + ... + n^2 + n + 1).$$ Because $n - 1$ is not divisible by $p$ we can say$$p|(n^{q-1} + n^{q-2} + n^{q - 3} + ... + n^2 + n + 1)$$

Comment: yah its correct.  But then how can I proceed @Luka Markovic

Answer (score 3):

So $n^q-1$ is divisible by $p$, meaning $n^q\equiv 1\mod p$. Since $p\not\mid n-1$, we know $n\not\equiv 1\mod p$. Now let $d$ be the smallest positive integer such that $n^d\equiv 1\mod p$ (that is, $d$ is the order of $n$ modulo $p$). Then $d>1$ and $d\mid q$: but since $q$ is prime, this means $d=q$. By the Fermat's Little Theorem however we see $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$, meaning $d\mid p-1$: this completes the proof, since now $q\mid p-1$.